# Alignment on Triangular Grids

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, hexagonal-grid

Hexagonal grids have been become a fairly popular twist for challenges about 2-dimensional data recently. However, it seems that the equally interesting triangular grids have been largely neglected so far. I'd like to rectify that with a rather simple challenge.

First, how do we represent a triangular grid? Consider the following example (ignore the right diagram for now):

[image] [image]

The cells neatly fall onto a regular grid (the difference to a regular grid being only which cells are considered adjacent):

```
1234567
89abcde
fghijkl
mnopqrs
```

Now, as the right diagram shows, a triangular grid has three main axes: a horizontal and two diagonal ones.

Highlighting these in the ASCII grid:

```
AVAVAVA
VAabcAV
fVAiAVl
mnVAVrs
```

#### The Challenge

You're given a rectangular string representing a triangular grid (where the top left corner is an upwards-pointing triangle). Most of the cells with be `.`, but exactly two cells will be `#`, e.g.:

```
....#
.#...
.....
```

Determine whether the two `#` are aligned along any of the three axes of the grid (i.e. whether they lie on a single row in any of the three directions highlighted above). For this example, the answer is "no".

You may write a program or function, taking input via STDIN (or closest alternative), command-line argument or function argument and outputting the result via STDOUT (or closest alternative), function return value or function (out) parameter.

Input may be a single string delimited by linefeeds or some other convenient character, or a list of strings. You may use any two (consistent) printable ASCII characters in place of `.` and `#`.

Output should be a [truthy](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey/2194#2194) value if the highlighted cells are aligned and a [falsy](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey/2194#2194) value otherwise.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

#### Test Cases

Truthy grids:

```
.#..#.

#
#

...........
...#.......
...........
...........
...........
.......#...
...........

...........
.......#...
...........
...........
...........
...#.......
...........

.#.........
...........
...........
...........
...........
.......#...
...........

...........
...#.......
...........
...........
...........
...........
.......#...

.........#.
...........
...........
...........
...........
...#.......
...........

...........
.......#...
...........
...........
...........
...........
...#.......

...........
.#.....#...
...........
...........
...........
```

Falsy grids:

```
#.....
.....#

.....#
#.....

...#.......
...........
...........
...........
...........
.......#...
...........

...........
...#.......
...........
...........
...........
...........
.........#.

.......#...
...........
...........
...........
...........
...#.......
...........

...........
.......#...
...........
...........
...........
...........
.#.........
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Snails](https://github.com/feresum/PMA), <s>40</s> 39 bytes

```
\#{z|=(ul.ul.`,l~a~)(l.a3|.a|d.ea5}.,\#
```

```
\#    ,, match '#'
{
  z |  ,, Either turn in any octinilear direction, or do all the other stuff before the }
  =(   ,, If this assertion succeeds, the starting cell is an "upwards-pointing triangle"
    ul.ul.`,  ,, Go one cell up or left twice, any number of times.
              ,, This should have been one byte shorter with ul.`2 , or ul.`2+? but 
              ,, the parsing of ` is buggy.
    l~a~   ,, Check that we are on the top-left cell by matching out-of-bounds to the left and then northeast
  )
  ( l.a3 |  ,, Move leftward once, then set direction to northwest; or
    .a   |  ,, Move right (the initial direction) once, then set direction to northeast; or
    d.ea5   ,, Move down once, then set direction to either northwest or northeast
}
.,    ,, Match any number of arbitrary chars (moving in the current direction)
\#    ,, match '#'
```

Answer (score 2):

### CJam, 47 bytes

Well, now that there is a shorter solution I no longer feel bad sharing my own. :) (Mostly to show that this isn't particularly difficult, even if you don't have a 2D pattern matching language...)

```
qN%:eeee::f+:~{S&},2f<:P0f=P::+Xf|P::-Xf|]::=:|
```

This uses spaces in place of `#` and really anything else for `.`.

[Run all test cases online.](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cU4yKi97OlE7CgpRTiU6ZWVlZTo6Zis6fntTJn0sMmY8OlAwZj1QOjorWGZ8UDo6LVhmfF06Oj06fAoKXW9Ob30v&input=LiAuLiAuCgogCiAKCi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uCi4uLiAuLi4uLi4uCi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uCi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uCi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uCi4uLi4uLi4gLi4uCi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uCgouLi4uLi4uLi4uLgouLi4uLi4uIC4uLgouLi4uLi4uLi4uLgouLi4uLi4uLi4uLgouLi4uLi4uLi4uLgouLi4gLi4uLi4uLgouLi4uLi4uLi4uLgoKLiAuLi4uLi4uLi4KLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4KLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4KLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4KLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4KLi4uLi4uLiAuLi4KLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4KCi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uCi4uLiAuLi4uLi4uCi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uCi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uCi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uCi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uCi4uLi4uLi4gLi4uCgouLi4uLi4uLi4gLgouLi4uLi4uLi4uLgouLi4uLi4uLi4uLgouLi4uLi4uLi4uLgouLi4uLi4uLi4uLgouLi4gLi4uLi4uLgouLi4uLi4uLi4uLgoKLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4KLi4uLi4uLiAuLi4KLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4KLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4KLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4KLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4KLi4uIC4uLi4uLi4KCi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uCi4gLi4uLi4gLi4uCi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uCi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uCi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uCgogLi4uLi4KLi4uLi4gCgouLi4uLiAKIC4uLi4uCgouLi4gLi4uLi4uLgouLi4uLi4uLi4uLgouLi4uLi4uLi4uLgouLi4uLi4uLi4uLgouLi4uLi4uLi4uLgouLi4uLi4uIC4uLgouLi4uLi4uLi4uLgoKLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4KLi4uIC4uLi4uLi4KLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4KLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4KLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4KLi4uLi4uLi4uLi4KLi4uLi4uLi4uIC4KCi4uLi4uLi4gLi4uCi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uCi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uCi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uCi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uCi4uLiAuLi4uLi4uCi4uLi4uLi4uLi4uCgouLi4uLi4uLi4uLgouLi4uLi4uIC4uLgouLi4uLi4uLi4uLgouLi4uLi4uLi4uLgouLi4uLi4uLi4uLgouLi4uLi4uLi4uLgouIC4uLi4uLi4uLg&debug=on)

I really hate the duplication in `P::+Xf|P::-Xf|` but so far I haven't come up with anything to get rid of it.

#### Explanation

Don't read on if you want to figure out a solution for yourself.

First, the boring part: getting the two coordinate pairs of the two spaces in the input grid:

```
qN%   e# Read input and split into lines.
:ee   e# Enumerate the characters in each line. I.e. turn each character 'x into a pair
      e# [N 'x] where N is its horizontal 0-based index.
ee    e# Enumerate the lines themselves, turning each line [...] into [M [...]] where M
      e# is its vertical 0-based index.
::f+  e# This distributes the vertical index over the individual lines, by prepending it
      e# to each pair in that line. So now we've got a 2-D array, where each character 'x
      e# has been turned into [M N 'x].
:~    e# Flatten the outermost dimension, so that we have a flat list of characters with
      e# their coordinates.
{S&}, e# Filter only those lists that contain a space.
2f<   e# Truncate the two results to only their first two elements.
:P    e# Store the result in P.
```

Now the interesting part is how to determine whether those coordinates are aligned or not. My code computes all three axes separately:

- The horizontal axis is trivial. Check whether the vertical coordinates match.
- Let's look at the north-east diagonal. In the ASCII grid, there are always two antidiagonals that belong to each tri-grid diagonal:

  ```
  ....AV..
  ...AV...
  ..AV....
  ```

  We can identify the current antidiagonal by adding up the `x` and `y` coordinates:

  ```
  01234567
  12345678
  23456789
  ```

  So we'd want `0` and `1` to belong to the same diagonal, as well as `2` and `3`, and `4` and `5` and so on. That means, once we have our anti-diagonal index we want to round up to the next odd number. In other words, we take the bitwise OR with `1`. (We could also round down to the next even number by bitwise AND with `-2` but that's more expensive in code.)
- Now the south-east diagonals:

  ```
  .VA.....
  ..VA....
  ...VA...
  ```

  In order to give diagonals an index, we *subtract* the `x` from the `y` coordinate (representing negative numbers as letters):

  ```
  0abcdefg
  10abcdef
  210abcde
  ```

  In this case, we'd want `0` and `1` to belong to the same diagonal, as well as `-1` and `-2`, or `2` and `3`. So once again, we want to round up to the next odd number.

Here is the code for that:

```
0f=  e# The coordinates are still on the stack. Replace each with its vertical coordinate
     e# to check for the horizontal axis.
P    e# Push the coordinates again.
::+  e# Sum each pair to get an anti-diagonal index.
Xf|  e# OR each index with 1 to round up to the next odd number.
P    e# Push the coordinates again.
::-  e# In each pair, subtract the horizontal coordinate from the vertical, to
     e# get a diagonal index.
Xf|  e# OR each index with 1.
]    e# Wrap all three index pairs in an array.
::=  e# Check equality for each pair.
:|   e# Fold bitwise OR over the results to check if at least one pair of indices
     e# was equal.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>36</s> 27 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/when-can-apl-characters-be-counted-as-1-byte-each)

```apl
1∊=/¯1 0 1∘.(⊥-2|⊣×⊥)⍸⍉⍎¨↑⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97b/ho44uW/1D6w0VDBSA7Bl6Go@6luoa1TzqWnx4OpCp@ah3x6Pezke9fYdWPGqb@KhvKkjf/zQuIOtR24RHbZMNFcwe9W5RNzA0ACJ1LiQZI6CJQBlDQxRRcwVDsLABCjA0IA2gqSfCBlJswaIOuw2kOptCPxhSZhl@GwwpdD8N4gGLFhQbTLHYYEi8DWipFZyOkTQaYpOHyBji9a3hEEkTGDkWzQZDit1PyzRhiMUGsLnqCuBYBFLgSAQA)

*-9 bytes mostly from @Bubbler*

Full program that returns `0` or `1`. Takes input as an array of strings, where each character is `0` for `.` or `1` for `#`.

#### How?

Uses the same general strategy as Martin Ender's [CJam Answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/69064/68261). The two diagonals are indexed as `y+(-1)*x` and `y+1*x`, both rounded up to the nearest odd number. The horizontal axis is indexed as `y+0*x` with no rounding.

```apl
1∊=/¯1 0 1∘.(⊥-2|⊣×⊥)⍸⍉⍎¨↑⎕
                         ↑⎕  ⍝ The input array of strings, converted to a matrix
                       ⍎¨    ⍝ Evaluate each character to obtain either 0 or 1
                     ⍸       ⍝ Find the (y,x) positions of both 1s
          ∘.                 ⍝ Outer product:
    ¯1 0 1                     ⍝ For each ⍺ in 1, 0, -1:
                               ⍝ And for each (y,x) position
            (⊥     )           ⍝ Compute (⍺×x)+y (convert to base ⍺)
                                 ⍝ (⍉-Transposed earlier to get x left of y)
             -2|⊣×⊥            ⍝ If odd and ⍺ is not 0: subtract 1
1∊=/                         ⍝ Check if the two positions have equal indices on any axis
```

Comment: @Bubbler That exact code doesn't work e.g. for `'0000' '1000' '0001'` since it merges some rows together. My fix seems a bit long, but `@` seems to be the main other alternative, and `@1 3` is already +4 bytes, so it would not be shorter

Comment: Yeah, I realized that shortly after I posted it. It's possible to shorten the fixed version to [30 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v9rwUUeXrf6jnq5D6w0VDBSA3Bl6Go@6lh7ebqgNZNc86lqs@ah3x6Pezke9fYdWPGqb@Kh3a@3/tEdtE4ACj7qaH/WuedS75dB6Y5BU39TgIGcgGeLhGfw/TQHIAqlrm2yoYAZUpG5gaABE6lxIMkZAK4EyhoYoouYKhmBhAxRgaEAaQFNPhA2k2IJFHXYbSHU2hX4wpMwy/DYYUuh@GsQDFi0oNphiscGQeBvQUis4HSNpNMQmD5ExxNRvjCRvgNMUFFU4zUIKOcMhkr4wcj@aDYYUu5@W6QuhQR0A) btw.

Comment: @Bubbler Nice train; interestingly, that's closer to my original solution. I was able to shave off 2 more bytes since ⍵ was only used once

Comment: [27](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v9rwUUeXrf6h9YYKBgpA9gw9jUddS3WNah51LT48HcjUfNS741Fv56PevkMrHrVNfNS7tfZ/2qO2CUCBR13Nj3rXPOrdcmi9MUiqb2pwkDOQDPHwDP6fpgBkgdS1TTZUMAMqUjcwNAAidS4kGSOglUAZQ0MUUXMFQ7CwAQowNCANoKknwgZSbMGiDrsNpDqbQj8YUmYZfhsMKXQ/DeIBixYUG0yx2GBIvA1oqRWcjpE0GmKTh8gYYuo3RpI3wGkKiiqcZiGFnOEQSV8YuR/NBkOK3U/L9IXQoA4A) using "round down to even".